# how to convert the flex date object to MySQL date and time?

Tags: apache-flex, datetime

how to convert flex date objec to sql date and time,

i am using AMFPHP to connect with mysql

need help

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the date to string of flex will give you the format like

Day Mon Date HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY

but sql is like

2010-12-14 00:00:00

so what you do is make a string of the sql format and just pass as object to AMFPHP that will save it to sql

and sql will accept it as date time

```
private function dateToString(date:Date):String
        {
            var dateString:String = date.fullYear+"-"+(date.month+1)+"-"+date.date+" "+date.hours+":"+date.minutes+":"+date.seconds;    
            return dateString;
        }//end function
```

cheers....

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the date is sent as string. In that case, use mysql function STR_TO_DATE()